# Mongoose unable to signup user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got an **ValidatorError** when trying to add a new user using my API... I get the following error, even though the required fields are submitted. I can't really figure out why. I've added the relevant part of the code. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhKkK.png)

Here is my code:
userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!'],
  },
  mobile: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your mobile number!'],
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default.jpg',
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false,
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      //This only works on create and save
      validator: function (el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not the same!',
    },
  },

  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false,
  },

  referralCode: String,
  address: String,
  occupation: String,
  education: String,
  socialSiteLink: String,
  maritalStatus: String,
  religion: String,
  language: String,
  employmentStatus: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

authControler.js

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');

exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user: newUser,
    },
  });
});
```

catchAsync.js

```
module.exports = (fn) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

Comment: can you provide the rest of the error properties `kind:`,`path:` ,`value:` ,`reason:` ?

Comment: {"status":"error","error":{"errors":{"passwordConfirm":{"name":"ValidatorError","message":"Please confirm your password","properties":{"message":"Please confirm your password","type":"required","path":"passwordConfirm"},"kind":"required","path":"passwordConfirm"},"password":{"name":"ValidatorError","message":"Please provide a password","properties":{"message":"Please provide a password","type":"required","path":"password"},"kind":"required","path":"password"}